# How do I output a file from outside public://

Tags: 7, files

I'm outputting an image at urls starting with `image-for`, e.g. `image-for/example/path` would choose an appropriate image for `example/path`. Basically this looks up the first image from a field for the given node, and defaults to a site logo.

My code therefore looks like

```
<?php
// ...
$file = mymod_get_appropriate_file_uri();
if (!$file) $file = "/sites/all/modules/mymod/standard-file.png";

// the headers are generated, code omitted as it works correctly!
$headers = array(); 

file_transfer($file, $headers);
drupal_exit();
```

This works fine for files in `public://`.

The problem seems to be that [file_transfer()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_transfer/7) can't handle files that don't have a schema. The file I want to transfer is not in `public://`, so prepending that won't work. **How can I get it to output the file?**

Nb. as a work-around I'm currently redirecting to the URL, but I don't like this.